# EC-2 suddenly stopped sending smtp.gmail.com mail - connection timeout

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail

Im running a Laravel 6 app on AWC EC-2 instance and have it configured to send mail via Gmail SMTP. Has worked perfect for nearly 2 years. Approx 1-1.5 days ago, the email function started throwing the Connection timed out error.

I tried switching ports, and changing TLS to SSL and no change.

Ive read dozens of threads with the same problem - but no help. Most suggest changing from driver smtp to sendmail - but that breaks all my email-send code.

I tried to telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 from the command line - and get Host is unreachable. There has been NO change to the code, config or setup recently.

My thoughts right now, are either:

1. AWS have blocked my smtp port,
2. Google has blocked my IP from sending mail,
3. My server MAY have reached a limit of some sort (but thought it will un-suspend in 24hrs if the case)

I am not sure HOW or WHERE to find that answer, or if there is another possible problem/solution here. I only have Basic support with AWS - so cant raise a standard tech support q.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

With thanks - James (Image of error and env below).

[image]

Comment: You should contact gmail and ask them. It's likely they blocked your servers if they got flagged for suspicious activity.